# Convert API call into a csv file with selected attributes in columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have access public API data by given below link.

```
import json,urllib
import csv
data = urllib.urlopen("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-10-01&endtime=2016-10-02").read()
output = json.loads(data)
print (output)
```

need help to put the obtained data into a csv file. With Following attributes should be the columns in the csv file:
•   Latitude (Hint: Treat, the first entry in coordinates attribute as Lat)
•   Longitude (Hint: Treat, the second entry in the coordinates attribute as Longitude)
•   Title : This should include the Earthquake description
•   Place: The location of the Earthquake
•   Mag: Magnitude of the earthquake

And then to convert into Pandas dataframe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this directly using [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv) and by requesting CSV data in the HTTP request:

```
import pandas as pd

url_csv = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=csv&starttime=2016-10-01&endtime=2016-10-02'
df = pd.read_csv(url_csv, usecols=['latitude', 'longitude', 'place', 'mag'])
```

Notice that I have changed the URL to request the data in CSV format by setting `format=csv`, and that `pd.read_csv()` accepts a URL for the data. `usecols` selects those columns to retain.

The CSV file does not contain the `title` column, however that column seems to be composed of the magnitude and location columns so, although you might want to avoid adding duplicate data, it can be constructed and appended to the dataframe like this:

```
df['title'] = 'M ' + df['mag'].map(str) + ' - ' + df['place']
```

---

There is also a [`pd.read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) Pandas function, but I wasn't able to easily get it to work. If you can figure it out then you should be able to extract the required data without manually composing the title column.

Comment: Thanks Sir, but dataframe display not appeared for further analysis

Comment: No problem. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Sir please help for to find How many times the earthquake has occurred in at a place where the place description contains the string “California”? from the above CSV data

Comment: `df['place'].str.contains('California').value_counts()[True]`. Or `len(df[df['place'].str.contains('California')])`

Answer (score 0):

if could be helpful I used the following code to get and import data in Google Spreadsheet from source which gave an API.

So, in Google Spreadsheet type:

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://{site.com}/api/{API version, eg. V3}/datasets/{page_reference_where document is in}/{name_doc}.csv?api_key={your api key}")
```